# The values of a vector in python are shown as nan value

Tags: python, complex-numbers, python-cmath

I have a vector `y` with size, for example, (1,64). I create a vector in python as follows:

```
vec = np.pi * np.sqrt(-1) * range(len(y))
```

I get the output values of the vector  `vec` are all `nan`  or the majority of them are `nan`.

What i'm trying to accomplish with `range(len(y))` in the above code, is to create a vector including 0, 2, 3, ... with the length of `y`.

How can I solve that issue, please?

Comment: why `sqrt(-1)`??

Comment: Also, why do 2 * 0.5 ????

Comment: (And look at the second answer, not the one with `cmath`: numpy doesn't switch to complex numbers automatically, you have to provide a complex input, `numpy.sqrt(-1+0j)` will work and return `1j` - or you could simply write that directly of course)

Comment: `sqprt(-1)` is corresponding into the value `j`

Comment: @Fatima_Ali if you know that already, why do you fight with writing `sqrt(-1)`?

Comment: `np.pi*1j*np.array(range(len(y)))` should work.

Comment: @JohnColeman it does work, tried it already just to be sure, when read "however you can't use mathematical operations on it as is" below

Comment: @JohnColeman I misread your comment, so the explicit `array` is not needed, `2*np.pi*np.sqrt(1+0j)*0.5*range(len(y))` is the one I tried and works already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting nan because you're using the square root of -1, as for `range(len(y))` it creates a range object with items from 0 to `len(y) - 1`, however you can't use mathematical operations on it as is, you need to pass it to `numpy.array` or have a numpy object in the expression , (this is satisfied by `np.sqrt` function), another way would be `np.array(range(len(y)))`

a working example:

`vec = 2*np.pi*np.sqrt(1)*0.5*range(len(y))`

if you'd like to use imaginary units you need to express the number as an complex number use the expression `i+jk`

so your code would be ( 2 *0.5 removed because it's redundant)

`vec = np.pi*np.sqrt(-1 + 0j)*np.array(range(len(y)))`

Comment: yes, but I mean by the `sqrt(-1)` is the value of imaginary number `j`. How can I replace it with `j`?

Comment: @Fatima_Ali that would be `np.sqrt(-1+0j)`

Comment: @JohnColeman that would work as well, but if you need the square root of a complex variable then np.sqrt(x + k*1j) would be more dynamic

Comment: @JohnColeman did you try the code ? it works perfectly fine , as for your first point it's right `0.5 * 2 is redundant` but the problem was with nan and how to get rid with while getting the square root of -1 , i did edit my answer to mark the range to numpy array conversion

Answer (score 1):

you need complex class like below:

```
import cmath

vec = 2*np.pi * cmath.sqrt(-1)*0.5* np.array(range(len(y)))
vec
```

output:

```
array([0.+0.j        , 0.+3.14159265j, 0.+6.28318531j, 0.+9.42477796j])
```

Comment: @ Fatima_Ali, you need `cmath`, you can use above easy code :))